# is bfgminer running correctly?

Tags: bfgminer

As a complete newbie I purchased USB ASIC mining device, installed bfgminer on raspberry pi and tried to run it. As the reward is not changing, I am wondering whether bfgminer is running correctly.

This is the snapshot of bfgminer:
[image]

And this is the snapshot of workers status in Slush's pool:
[image]

I would be very thankful if anyone could tell whether this is working correctly or how to check in general if everything is OK.

Answer (score -1):

When i look at the snapshot it seems like your device isn't hashing. Did you have your device hashing? and did you get the USB TO UART DRIVER BY SILICONE LABS? respond when you have the answers.